# How to transform this SMS gateway Java code to Android Studio Code

Tags: android

I need help transforming this code from Java to Android Studio Java. It's an SMS gateway code, trying to use it in my Android application to send SMS to users.

```
private static String doHttpPost(String urlString, String requestString) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(requestString);
        wr.flush();
        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String response = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response += line;
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();

        return response;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex); return ex.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What SMS gateway are you using? It should work so long as it is wrapped in an AsyncTask.

Comment: @Helix am using cm telecoms, how can i wrap it with AsyncTask

Comment: am getting a red line under URL @Helix

Comment: what is your import for url? it should be java.net.URL

Comment: an asynctask is a way of handling operations in the background without clogging the main ui thread. [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: am having fatal error in this part of the code `OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());` @Helix

Comment: the problem am having is that AsyncTask uses three values but in the main method am only passing two values into my dohttp method, giving me issues` String response = new doHttpTask().execute(URL,xml);`

Comment: if you specify AsynckTask<Void, Void, Void> you can call it without passing anything into it. then override the default constructor to include whatever variables you want to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
public class PostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

   String requestString;
   String urlString;

   public PostAsyncTask(String urlString, String requestString){
      this.urlString = urlString;
      this.requestString = requestString;
   }


   @Override
   String doInBackground(Void... void){

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(requestString);
        wr.flush();
        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReade(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String response = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response += line;
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();

        return response;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex); return ex.toString();
    }

   }

    @Override
    onPostExecute(String result){

        //Code to handle result here

    }



}
```

Call this from your code using

```
new PostAsyncTask(urlString, requestString).execute();
```